# Turtlebot Gazebo tutorial can't find diagnostics.yaml

Tags: gazebo, simulation, turtlebot, tutorial, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to follow exactly the tutorial listed on this page:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Map%20in%20TurtleBot%20Simulator

When I try to launch the simulation with `roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo_tutorial build_map.launch`, I end up with this error:

```
turtlebot@TurtleBook:~/sim_workspace/unversioned/turtlebot_gazebo_tutorial$ roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo_tutorial build_map.launch
... logging to /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/a2f359fc-e800-11e2-9907-dc85de7b0a3a/roslaunch-TurtleBook-4029.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

error loading <rosparam> tag: 
    file does not exist [/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_bringup/config/diagnostics.yaml]
XML is <rosparam command="load" file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/config/diagnostics.yaml"/>
```

Sure enough, I have a turtlebot_bringup folder, but there is no "config" subfolder. I'm very much a newbie to ROS and TurtleBot in general; would anybody please be able to tell me why I'm missing this file or how I should have generated it?

I am running TurtleBot 2 (Kobuki base) on ROS Groovy and Ubuntu 12.04

The only thing I have done differently from following the tutorial exactly is replace a single line in robot.launch. Originally this:

```
<launch>   <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find turtlebot_description)/urdf/turtlebot.urdf.xacro'" />
```

I used this instead:

```
<launch>
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find turtlebot_description)/urdf/turtlebot_gazebo.urdf.xacro'" />
```

I did this because there *was* a turtlebot.urdf.xacro in myturtlebot_description folder, but only in the "graveyard" subfolder. This caused an error and the name suggested to me that the launch file on the tutorial was somewhat outdated. Changing to the turtlebot_gazebo.urdf.xacro file fixed this error, but now I have the error listed above.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66826/turtlebot-gazebo-tutorial-can%27t-find-diagnostics.yaml/) by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on ROS Answers with karma: 504 on 2013-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TurtleBot simulation is not supported in Groovy.

You either have to use Fuerte or wait for the new TurtleBot simulation in Hydro.

Sorry.

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on 2013-07-09**:
Oh...that's a shame. Thank you for your time.